# Save MATLAB GUI as html page file?

Tags: html, matlab, function, user-interface, save

I've been told that it's possible to save a MATLAB GUI as an html file so that it can be accessed outside of MATLAB but I can't find anything that says how to do it. Is this possible? I want to demonstrate my GUI on another PC which doesn't have MATLAB installed on it.

Comment: no, it is not possible. Matlab does not run in a browser. You can buy the Matlab compiler, and compile to .exe (see some limitations on which toolboxes supported, etc.. at mathworks web site) http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need the code to actually work, you'll need matlab or, as [Nasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765271/nasser) says, MCR, on your other computer.

But if you just want to show the GUI, you should be able to just grab frames of the gui programmaticaly via either [grabbing the frame and then writing it to images](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/111445), or using the [MATLAB publishing framework](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html)